# How to increment a column value if it repeats, otherwise reset to 1?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of image URL's and other column is "Image Position". So if the image URL has the same "Base ID" I would like Position column to increment from 1. If the Base value differs, I'd like to reset back to 1.

For example (you see all end with **foobar-8.jpg** .. I need way to check if **foobar** changes and if it does start back at 1. Otherwise keep incrementing +1 like below? Is this doable with VBA? I can't figure out with regular Excel (2013).

[image]

Comment: Use COUNTIF: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: Can you explain how that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)
```

The thing to pay attention to in the formula I suggested is the absolute and relative cell coordinates. As you populate it down, `A$2` stays the same and `A2` increments up, so 5 rows down, the formula becomes: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A7,A7)` which means is counts all instances of the value in `A7` in all the previous rows

An explanation of `COUNTIF` can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34